# Issue with Docker Installation on MacOS - build fails and world/authserver executable seems missing

Tags: docker, azerothcore

I'm having troubles with the '[Install with Docker](https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/install-with-docker)' guide that is on your page. (Running on MacOS)

Whenever I'm at the compilation step and it runs through everything, I notice the following errors cropping up:
Right after entering command:

```
NOTICE: file </Users/<user>/azerothcore-wotlk/conf/config.sh> has not been found, you should create and configure it.
Deno version check:
/Users/rukazisintakumo/azerothcore-wotlk/apps/bash_shared/deno.sh: line 18: ./deps/deno/bin/deno: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Then stuff still runs through and during the end of the building process, I get:

```
[ 99%] Building CXX object src/server/worldserver/CMakeFiles/worldserver.dir/CommandLine/CliRunnable.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable worldserver
clang: error: unable to execute command: Killed
clang: error: linker command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [src/server/worldserver/CMakeFiles/worldserver.dir/build.make:174: src/server/worldserver/worldserver] Error 254
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1159: src/server/worldserver/CMakeFiles/worldserver.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:130: all] Error 2
```

The process still finishes, and if I then run the containers, I get:

```
ac-authserver_1          | Deno version check:
ac-authserver_1          | Version 1.9.1 is already installed
ac-authserver_1          | Running authserver ...
ac-authserver_1          | /azerothcore/env/dist/bin/authserver doesn't exists!
azerothcore-wotlk_ac-authserver_1 exited with code 1
ac-worldserver_1         | Deno version check:
ac-worldserver_1         | Version 1.9.1 is already installed
ac-worldserver_1         | Running worldserver ...
ac-worldserver_1         | /azerothcore/env/dist/bin/worldserver doesn't exists!
```

I have attempted it 3 times now and I honestly don't know anymore what is going on... Can you help me out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: can you include the actual error from the compilation?

Comment: Thank you @FrancescoBorzi I have added the full compilation process here on this Pastebin https://pastebin.com/wE44AG9s 
I hope this is useful.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I got the solution for that problem now.
The conf file that was reported missing was the culprit here. After copying the file from the dist folder into the requested one the complication completed successfully.